# Proper prepositions and word choice in "thought of st. like ...." sentence

Tags: word-choice, prepositions

I am not sure if I wrote this sentence in proper English:

> Since the inference lies in special estimation, we thought of a prior
> more like abstract function rather than a prior distribution.

Did I use correct words and am I not missing some prepositions there? Not sure if the choice of word "like" is correct, whether there should be "as" instead or if both are correct; also not sure if there shouldn't be another "of" like this? :

> we thought of a prior
> more **like of an** abstract function rather than a prior distribution

or like this:

> we thought of a prior
> more **as of an** abstract function rather than a prior distribution

or just like this:

> we thought of a prior
> more **like an** abstract function rather than a prior distribution

or like this? :

> we thought of a prior
> more **as an** abstract function rather than a prior distribution

Comment: Assuming you're talking about statistics and Bayesian probability, you should probly say something like _we think of a prior as more like an abstract function than a prior distribution_. Present tense, and _more like an X than a Y_ does everything you need. The rest is just detritus.

Comment: @JohnLawler thanks! So you do use both "as" and "like". Thanks. This was difficult one for me :-)

Comment: Why was this question marked as off-topic? "Research you have done" - not sure how to make "research" in case of specific phrase or context, dictionary's not helpful there. Show me then how can you answer this with commony available reference?